# Stackmob push notification logs?

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, stackmob

I am sending push notification through stackmob . It first gives log as

"Pushed to [2384740BD0B06EAA8635B33CF58B6E2693E8EAC41B6E7F085DE4DA6955D47098]"

then after certain time it says

"No push tokens found while pushing to 1 tokens with payload {"alert":"New alert(s) available","badge":"1","type":"1"}."

It gave me the headbang . Can anybody please help in lightening up the logs meaning ?

Also its not pushing notification to device ....